# Complicated If loops

Tags: matlab

Does anybody know if there is a simple way to make this kind of if-loop:

If a or b (or more of them) equal 1, then the new value of ONLY those variables that are true changes to e.g. 5?!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, if I understood your problem correctly

```
newValue = 5;
valueToFind = 1;
vector = [2 3 4 6 1 3 2 1 3];

vector(vector==valueToFind) = newValue;
```

**Update** (to respond to your comment below):

There's is no one right way to do it, but I would probably make a "table" of values to look for and what to reapace with their new counterparts. For example,

```
valuesTable = [1 3 4 6 9;... %#old values
               2 0 5 7 0];   %#new values
```

You could then go through them as follows:

```
vector = [2 3 4 6 1 3 2 1 3];

valuesTable = [1 3 4 6 9;... %#old values
               2 0 5 7 0];   %#new values

N = size(valuesTable,2);     %#count indices to go through

for n = 1:N
    old = valuesTable(1,n);  %#get current old value
    new = valuesTable(2,n);  %#get corresp. new value

    vector(vector==old) = new; %#replace the values
end
```

There could be other approaches rather than my "table" approach, but I find it clear, palpable and easy to read.

Comment: Merci my friend, but let's say I have 5 different indices and a vector(1:10). Now in each new generation, I want to replace each of these with a new value, based on a value they currently have. I have to make it all in one step - according to what you suggested, my vector keeps changing with every step.

Comment: any given numerical numbers (let it be 1 to 5 for example)

Answer (score 0):

To extend Phonon's answer to the case where you have several values to find, use `ismember`.

```
newValue = 5;
valuesToFind = [1 3];
vector = [2 3 4 6 1 3 2 1 3];

vector(ismember(vector, valuesToFind)) = newValue
```